# Clarification on the Proof of $\cos \theta=\frac{a^{\mathrm{T}} b}{\|a\|\|b\|}$ for higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

Below is the  proof given by Gilbert strang on pg 154 ,of the Cosine Formula :$\cos \theta=\frac{a^{\mathrm{T}} b}{\|a\|\|b\|}$

Before the proof, the only relevant thing the author defines is the inner product of two vectors $a, b$ given by $a^T.b$ and the orthogonality condition $a^Tb =0$

*Authors proof*:

[image]

**Law of Cosines**: $\quad\|b-a\|^{2}=\|b\|^{2}+\|a\|^{2}-2\|b\|\|a\| \cos \theta$

For angle $\theta$, the expression $\|b-a\|^{2}$ is $(b-a)^{T}(b-a)$, and above  equation  becomes
$$
b^{\top} b-2 a^{\mathrm{T}} b+a^{\mathrm{T}} a=b^{\mathrm{T}} b+a^{\mathrm{T}} a-2\|b\|\|a\| \cos \theta
$$
Canceling $b^{\top} b$ and $a^{\top} a$ on both sides of this equation, you recognize the formula for cosine: $a^{\top} b=\|a\|\|b\| \cos \theta .$
**In fact, this proves the cosine formula in $n$ dimension since we only have to worry about the plane triangle $\mathrm{Oab}$**

**Question**: How does this prove the cosine formula in $n$ dimensions ?
The author assumes that the law of cosines works for all higher dimensional vectors without proving it .

Furthermore what does "we only have to worry about the plane triangle $\mathrm{Oab}$" mean in higher dimensions?

Can anyone please help me understand this? It has been a day  but I'm not getting it, if you can only hint, I'd be glad.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What he means by "we only have to worry about the plane triangle Oab" is that the vectors a, b give rise to a 2D-triangle as in the picture. So we can just view the two vectors within the plane they span and not worry about the rest of the surrounding space.

In this light, it also makes sense that we can apply the law of cosines. As our vectors lie inside a 2D plane and we already know the law of cosines holds for triangles in 2D space, we can apply the law of cosines to the lengths of the vectors $a$, $b$ and $b - a$.

Comment: How can you say that , two vectors  say $[1,2,2,3,5]^T$and $[2,3,6,9,8]^T$  form a triangle? We can't visualise these vectors, then how come you say they form a triangle??

Comment: @Kashmiri The subspace spanned by two (non-parallel) vectors is a plane, regardless of the dimension of the ambient space. Yadeses has it right: you can forget the oddities of working in a "large" space and just pretend you're on a plane anyway.

Comment: Hi Dear Cameron, How do I visualize a vector (1,1,1,1) ?

Comment: If we consider two vectors in 3D space, we can see that the vectors span a 2D plane. This also holds in higher dimensions, so we can say that 2 5D vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ form a 2D plane: namely the collection of all linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: I do agree that 2 vectors form a subspace, but precisely how do you visualize  (1,1,1,1)  as a vector ? It's impossible to visualize it, and hence to say that there exists a triangle.

Comment: The trick is now to forget about everything except the subspace and only look at the vectors inside this subspace. For example, the vector $v_1 = (1,1,1,1)$ and $v_2 = (0, 0, 0, 1)$, we might visualize as spanning a 2D plane, where $v_2$ corresponds to $(0,1)$ and $v_1$ to $(\sqrt{3}, 1)$.

Comment: I agree with much of you said, but at the end saying these two vectors form a triangle is just imagination. They don't form it neither can we visuvalize them. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Kashmiri A plane exists also only in our imagination. Nevertheless you understand what a triangle means.

Comment: Hi, I agree but how to visualize a vector (1,1,1,1) ? It's impossible. So how does a triangle exist?

Comment: @Kashmiri you can visualize projections in higher dimensional spaces just as you can draw projections on paper for a three dimensional object with orthographic projections. The idea is to decompose the large object into a series of projections into a lower dimensional space that characterize the object in a higher dimensional space. For example a cube can be represented by three squares each projected onto a different plane.